# Java naming convention for entity to be persisted in different database

Tags: java, naming-conventions

We have legacy application which persists in database an entity named with User(it has the hibernate ORM annotations defined on it).
Now the DB migration is going to happen from MySQL to Mongo.(persisting the data in both storage system). In Mongo, the entity User is a POJO without annotation.
Is there any naming convention which can be followed so that the entity in different storage can be uniquely identified.

My thought was having same name of the model in different package or naming the entity with prefix of storage system like MongoUser.I am not so in favor of my approach.Please suggest.

Comment: Why should you use a different model? If mongo doesn't care about these annotations, then there shouldn't be any problem. And you don't need a way to convert your mysql models to mongo models.

Comment: @Tom: The ORM entity has defintion with Annotations , also if there are mapped tables they are included as Java Objects.However in Mongo the entities are plain POJO object with String/Integer getters setters.

Comment: Would mongo break if you provide him a model instance which has annotations it doesn't need? If not, then why would you prefer to double all your model class, apply a different name for them and to care about converting them if you like to move an entry of db A to db B? Just use the same model for both databases (if they could handle them).

Comment: Thanks @Tom: I need to check on the first part , and need to see how  hibernate works with reference object (FK) which are set on the entity , eventually which gets saved as varchar or other defined data type in the table.For mongo db we wanted to define the collection documents in simple POJO format.